# How do I combine/group multiple rows into one row

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having issues combining all the rows of the result of my query in one row.

Here's a snapit of my result

```
Column1    Column2                   Column3           Column4
1900200196 Null                                                          
1900200196 Null
1900200196 Null                      Intake and assmnt/eva
1900200196 Null                                        Staff interpreter 
1900200196 INTERPRETER
1900200196 Null
```

I would like my result to look like this

```
Column1     Column2              Column3             Column4
1900200196  MEDICAL INTERPRETER  Staff interpreter   Intake and assmnt/eval
```

Any assistance in the right direction will do.

Comment: What do you want to do if there is a column where more than one row has a non-null value ?

Comment: It seems it's unclear what happens when a column has multiple non-null values.

Comment: I assume `MEDICAL` is a typing error.

Answer (score 3):

```
select column1, 
       max(column2) as column2,
       max(column3) as column3,
       max(column4) as column4
from your_table
group by column1
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you want aggregation :

> ```
> with A as (
>     select 1900200196 as column1, null as column2, 'INTERPRETER' as column3, 'foo' as column4 FROM DUAL
>     UNION
>     select 1900200196, 'M', null, null FROM DUAL
> )
> SELECT column1, MAX(column2) column2, MAX(column3) column3, MAX(column4) column4 FROM A GROUP BY column1
> ```
>
> ```
>    COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 | COLUMN3     | COLUMN4
> ---------: | :------ | :---------- | :------
> 1900200196 | M       | INTERPRETER | foo
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=447c3e04b0330c54482ad8aa6e5d736d)*

Comment: Thanks much to everyone